# Convert SQL Server BIT datatype to boolean VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, boolean, bit

I'm a little rusty on my VB.NET especially when converting to SQL. I thought I had a simple task of hiding 2 buttons unless a checkbox is checked. The checkbox is bound to a SQL Server column with a `bit` data type.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CaseVehicleCollisionCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CaseVehicleCollisionCheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    Dim collision As System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary
    collision = CaseVehicleCollisionCheckBox1

    If collision = True Then
        btnVehicle1.Visible = True
        btnVehicle2.Visible = True
    ElseIf collision = False Then
        btnVehicle1.Visible = False
        btnVehicle2.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

I keep getting the error

> Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary'

when trying to assign the checkbox to the variable.

I get the same error when trying to use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean`

Comment: "The checkbox is bound to an SQL field " - huh?

Comment: @JeremyThompson - same results

Comment: Once you're using `Boolean` rather than `SqlBinary`, also note that there's no need for the `If` statement. Just say `btnVehicle1.Visible = collision` and `btnVehicle2.Visible = collision`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are casting a CheckBox control to a SQLBinary datatype and that isn't going to work.

I presume CaseVehicleCollisionCheckBox1 is the name of the CheckBox. You need to use the [`CheckBoxes Checked property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx), eg:

```
Dim collision As Boolean
collision = CaseVehicleCollisionCheckBox1.Checked
```

Comment: @jstacy00 your welcome, there's a tickbox next to each answer, ticking it gives you a couple of points and saves people from spending time troubleshooting this by letting them know its working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlBoolean instead of sqlBinary.
sqlBinary is the sql equivalent of an array of bytes.